# Parent div of specific height and width containing number of child div horizontally

Tags: html, css, slider

I have parent div(slider) of height:450px and width:960px, which have random number(here let us consider 5) of child div(pannel) of same height and width.

They must be arranged horizontally inside parent div, such that only one div fits parent div at a time, also only overflow-x:auto; no vertical scroll bar.

This is what i have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider_holder">
    <div class="slider">
        <span class="pannel"> </span>
        <span class="pannel"> </span>
        <span class="pannel"> </span>
        <span class="pannel"> </span>
        <span class="pannel"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, *
{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
}


.slider_holder
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
position:relative;
top:100px;
width:960px;
height:450px;
background:#eee;
overflow:auto;
}

.slider
{
width:auto;
height:100%;
}

.pannel
{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:960px;
height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Note**: I can achieve what i want if i give width:4800px; to slider div as 5x960 = 4800, but i don't want this hard coded, as number of child div could be any number.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hjs3eya/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because You are using `inline-block` elements You can user `white-space: nowrap;` property on slider:

```
.slider
{
width:auto;
height:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hjs3eya/1/)

Comment: I don't want it to arrange the div vertically, i want it to arrange in horizontal side by side inside slider div. [Like this](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/horizontalscroll.png)

Comment: @divy3993 I know. Did You checked fiddle? You should also remove `float: left` from `.pannel` class

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked very well for me, but i would like to understand what does it do. Please !

Comment: [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). `Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.` It disallows to break Your `<span></span>` tags into separate lines

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/dc38429f9a2de36a77e428bf833b240b) what you would like, you can use `calc` to change dimensions from percentages by pixels

```
.pannel {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 2px);
  height:calc(100% - 2px);
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` FTW! :)

Comment: @FelipeAls there's always the better option cx

Comment: I don't want it to arrange the div vertically, i want it to arrange in horizontal side by side inside slider div. [Like this](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/horizontalscroll.png)

Comment: @divy3993 use what FelipeAls said with `display:inline` and `overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: @divy3993 http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/97aa566fbf15a11b0914405c14396778